# Accelerometers: Can I separate linear measurement from gravitational measurement

Tags: accelerometer, hardware-acceleration

I am doing research on the tremors and Parkinson's disease.The plan is to use accelerometers and gyroscopes on the human arm. I plan on using Pulse for data collection and analysis. My questions are:

1. Is it true that there are some accelerometers that can separate gravitational acceleration from linear acceleration (heard it on the uncited grapevine). My suspicion is that we can't place an accelerometer on the patients arm to measure, say, the tremors caused by bicep and tricep contraction because if the patient rotates his wrist, the change in gravitational acceleration will contaminate our results. More to the point, can we measure acceleration due ONLY to the action of the muscles, and not due to changing gravitational forces with any of your accelerometers?
2. If a 3-axis accelerometer is rotating about an axis parallel to the ground, wouldn't the axis perpendicular to the ground pick up a sinusoidally varying (i.e. not DC) gravitational acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

None of the accelerometers can separate the linear acceleration from the gravitational acceleration. This is achieved by **sensor fusion**, you merge the accelerometer and gyro readings in a clever way.

I developed a motion sensing applicaton to [track human motion](http://reliablecomputing.eu/baharev-sensor-fusion.pdf) (elbow flexion). I am sure something similar would work fine for you.

My advice is to use orientation in your application (rotation matrices).

If you have to implement the sensor fusion yourself then the [Direction Cosine Matrix IMU: Theory](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9rLLz1XQKmaZTlQdV81QjNoZTA) manuscript is a good place to start.